# ¿Cómo añadir salto de línea con un explode?

Tags: php, split, explode

Buenas tardes esta es mi pagina de un registro de herramientas
¿Como puedo hacer un salto de linea cuando hay un punto?
que no este todo junto en donde dice Descripción como se muestra en la pagina.

case 'mostrar':
$rspta= mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT `ID`, `nombre`, `descripcion` FROM `sistema`.`sistema` WHERE  `ID`=$id;");
$rows = [];
while ($reg=$rspta->fetch_object()) {
$rows = array("id"=>$reg->ID,"nombre"=>$reg->nombre,"descripcion"=>$reg->descripcion);
}

```
    echo json_encode($rows);
    break;
case 'listar':
   
    $rspta= mysqli_query($conexion, "select ID, nombre, descripcion from sistema");
    $data=array();
    while($reg=$rspta->fetch_object()){
         $data[]=array(
        "0"=>'<button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" onclick="mostrarRegistro('.$reg->ID.')">Modificar</button><br>'.
        ' <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="desactivar('.$reg->ID.')">Eliminar</i></button>',
        "1"=>$reg->nombre,
        
        "2"=>$reg->descripcion); 
         
        
    }
    $results=array(
        "sEcho"=>1,//informacion para el datables
        "iTotalRecords"=>count($data),//enviamos el total registros al datatable
        "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data),//enviamos total de registros a visualizar
        "aaData"=>$data);
    echo json_encode($results);
    break;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! ordena tu pregunta.. escribir todo en mayuscula se considera gritar.. usa el boton [edit] y arregla todo... que lenguaje estas usando? cual es el problema concreto y en que parte de tu codigo esta?

Comment: as intentando con un  `"descripcion"=> str_replace(".", ".<br>", $reg->descripcion);` o arreglarlo en css con `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;word-break:break-all;`

Comment: En la imagen que muestras, en el registro que se ve completo (el primero) no hay ningún punto. Para cuando sepas cómo quieres introducir el fin de línea, podrías preprocesar el `$reg->descripcion` y reemplazarle algo con `algo+fin-de-linea`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes consultar la documentación de php: [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)

```
$bodytag = str_replace(".", ".<br>",$texto);
```